# Using async and unsafe

Tags: c#, asynchronous, unsafe

By the title of the question, one would immediately say "No, that is not possible!", but please keep reading.
(By the way I searched and there is no question such as this, so afaik this *is not* a duplicate)

Reading "Async in C# 5.0" I read

> **Unsafe Code**
>
> Code that is marked unsafe may not contain await. Unsafe code should be very rare and should be kept to self-contained methods that don't need to be asynchronous. The await compiler transformation would break the unsafe code in most situations anyway (Page 30)

What I gather from this, is that *inside* a unsafe block you can not write "await". 
But how about (and following my previous question) a function

```
void DoSomethingUnsafeHere(int[,] image)
{
  unsafe{
     }
}

async Task Caller()
{
   await Task.Run(() => DoSomethingUnsafeHere(image));
}
```

I am guessing this is possible with no problems, isn't it? 
Surely it seems this is a self-contained method. 
Any comments, recommendations on this will be greatly appreciated

Comment: There aren't many situations in my experience where "X may not contain Y" should automatically be assumed to imply "Y may not contain X".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there should be no problem with this.

<sup>(What kind of answer did you expect? `async` methods get transformed into a state machine by the compiler, which is the process that may break `unsafe` code. Calling methods is not a problem and it's irrelevant whether that method is `async`, `unsafe`, or any other kind of method.)</sup>